# Preventing session hijacking when using plain HTTP without encryption

Tags: http, security, session, cookies, https

From what I understand, if a user uses plain HTTP without TLS encryption layer then anyone listening "on the wire" can see the user's session cookie and steal it. So does this mean that it is impossible to guard against session hijacking if the website does not implement HTTP over TLS? Does it mean all websites before https could not guard against session hijacking?

The scenario might look like this.

**1. A good guy logs into their account**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: onlinecommunity.com
Cookie: PHPSESSID=f5avra_=AKMEHO_ga=GA1.2.93f54422f2ac010
```

**2. A bad guy listening "on the wire" sees the plain HTTP request**

**3. A bad guy sends the same request**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: onlinecommunity.com
Cookie: PHPSESSID=f5avra_=AKMEHO_ga=GA1.2.93f54422f2ac010
```

**4. Now the bad guy sees the good guy's profile!**

How did people prevent SESSION hijacking before HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer (in part) to my own question, so I'll share it here for others.

1. If the website doesn't use encryption then you can use a VPN to encrypt the requests, this way the session cookie will be hidden (encrypted)
2. You can re-create the session cookie with every request. Although from what I read this can be difficult to implement.
3. You can check against other header fields and compare them to the last request. If they are too different then you can block access.
4. You can check against the IP address. But since the person might be on mobile network the IP can change for legitimate reasons so you can at least to check against an IP range to make sure it's coming from the same country as the last request.

I suppose in general, if the website uses plain text HTTP without encryption, you can also steal their username and password by listening on the wire. So you should at least use a VPN (VPNs encrypt all data). I guess - never use plain text HTTP requests for any sensitive information.

Feel free to add or correct me.